Can liquid simulation particles rotation be aligned to their motion direction vector? If so, how?
I know nothing about fluid simulation add-ons, I'm referring here to Blender 4.2.1 default fluid simulator.
I'm trying to make some river-like things. I don't like how the foam looks in the simulation if using round objects for the particles. I've stretched them so that they form streaks which look much better to me on river-like bodies. The problem is tho I can align them at first to match the water channel direction, after the flow direction changes the particles rotation is unaltered and it no longer looks right.
I see in the Particles properties I can align the particles rotation to that of the object rotation, but it looks like this rotation is applied to all particles all the same, and even if it's applied individually to each particle, I just don't know how to insert each particle direction vector to align their rotation accordingly.
Is this even possible?
Thanks.

Update:
I'm still unsure this can be done but one thing that may be possible is changing the material shader accordingly. If I can only figure out how to read each particle rotation values I may be able to feed them into a wave texture and this into the Principled BSDF Alpha to create the illusion that the geometry is changing.
I found a video tutorial where the guy's using the positions to create a node group that will indicate the rotation, but that's one step ahead of me as I still haven't figured out how to read the particles data in the material shader.
I have tinkered with Particle Info, Point Info and Point Density nodes, but they all seem to be giving me 0 in their outputs. It's strange that Point Density will give me the possibility of selecting the actual liquid domain object and its specific foam particles but doesn't provide useful output for this purpose the way I see it.
I have no idea why the other Particle and Point nodes don't seem to give anything useful in their outputs. I would expect values directly out of them but maybe it doesn't work like this. Am I supposed to connect these outputs into another node in order to signify the other node output, as in if I connect the Particle Info Angular Velocity output directly to the Base Color input at the Principled BSDF it won't work but if I plug it instead to a color ramp before that it will? Although I have used Blender sparingly for years I'm often lost about how nodes actually work.
I'll keep tinkering. Meanwhile feel free to point out anything you think may help in the comments if you will...
